# Where to install Wordpress in CPanel?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, shared, cpanel, hosts

I'm a newbie on hosting blogs. I have a shared hosting account on HostGator that uses cpanel, and I want to install multiple wordpress sites.

I have my wp sites under /home/username/public_html/, so each site has its own directory under public_html. The problem is for my primary domain, the one I got from the hosting. It was installed under the public_html itself, so my other sites were accessible from the primary site, like http://www.primarysite/other-site. Is this the typical structure of hosting multiple wp sites on shared hosts?

Is it ok to have my other sites accessible under the primary site?

A detailed explanation would be very useful, or just point me to some good tutorials/articles. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can acces your other sites under your primary domain. For that you have to install wordpress under different directories.

I think you may be aware of [addon domain](http://hioxindia.com/faq/domain-hosting/addon-domain.php) feature. Try using the *addon domain* feature in your **cPanel**.

- You have two domains **mysite.com** and **my-other-site.com.**
- You want the two domains to be totally separate/independent websites.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is kind of confusing. My question was actually this, is it ok that my other sites can be accessed through my primary domain? such as http://primarydomain/othersite? Shouldn't they be independent of each other, would this be a security issue? or SEO issue? if a link (such as http://primarydomain/othersite) is indexed?

Comment: there will not be any problem in accessing your sites like  primarydomain.com/othersite.I don't think there will be a security issue or SEO. You can also make the othersite's url(primarydomain.com/othersite) as a subdomain(othersite.primarydomain.com) if you wish using your cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create different folders/directories for your other wordpress sites under public_html, and yes you can access your other site like www.primarysite.com/othersite only

Answer (score 1):

Hostgator cPanel includes Softaculous or Fantastico Auto Installers and both of them include Wordpress MU (wordpress multisite/multiuser) Follow the instructions and you can install multiple wordpress sites in a single click ;)